# WordPress change or remove custom post slug from url using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, custom-post-type

I'm developing a website using wordpress. I have custom post type urls like :

```
review/assassins-creed-iii/
```

But the post type name is *review*, but I have to rewrite this word to *product*

```
    product/assassins-creed-iii/
```

or

```
    assassins-creed-iii/
```

It's ok me to remove that slug and show only the post slug

I used this htaccess code :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (.*)/review/(.*)
RewriteRule .* example.com/%1/product/%2  [QSA,R=301,L]
```

But this redirects me to `404 page`. Anyone know how to change all urls as above?

Thank you

Comment: How are you adding the custom post type?

Comment: there have plugin installed and it use custom post type to store reviews

Comment: Try re saving settings>permalinks after the htaccess changes. Otherwise i would look into how to add your own custom post types, its not much code at all needed, then you can set the permalink yourself.

Comment: saved but the same issue happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed this using 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/
this allows me to change any permlinks

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try to this

```
RewriteRule ^review/(.*)   /products/$1   [L]
```

This will find "review" and replace it with products.

Comment: thanks but im getting
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: Just to confirm, you have this line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gamershighway.com$` at the top?

Comment: ni have like this
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/review/(.*)$ $1/products/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^review/(.*)$ products/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: i added this like below
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^review/(.*)   /products/$1   [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress but no luck, thanks